# How to get vscode TS intellisense to auto import node's util module

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, auto-import

I have a typescript (mainly) project with the following configurations in my `tsconfig.json`.

```json
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "ESNext",
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
```

However, if I try and use the `path.join()` function from `NodeJs` and then press ⌘+. (open code actions) the action `import 'path' from "path";` does not appear. Only other packages (like `filenamify`).

What should I do to allow all of `NodeJs`'s StdLib be auto-importable. I am working on an electron app, so technically any code should be able to use all of node.

Comment: Have you read [vscode docu related to typescript](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript)?

Comment: Yes, I don't see how any information on the website helps. It does have a section on auto imports but it only says that it is a thing and can be disabled.

I have it enabled so that is not the problem.

Comment: This [post](https://diarybydhanushka.dev/2020/03/13/how-to-fix-typescript-intellisense-not-loading-issue-in-vs-code/) I found as well.

Comment: Thank you. However, to repeat. It is not that I don't have any intellisense. Just that the node std-lib packages are never part of the "auto-import intellisense"